# How to find related terms in documents

Tags: nlp, information-retrieval, hierarchical-clustering, information-extraction

Want to cluster related terms to my query term . Terms should be related and not with similar meaning . Take example of term 'India' , I want to cluster related terms like 'Bollywood' , 'Taj Mahal' , 'Kari' , 'Nepal' ,'China' which represent some link with term 'India' .

I am using frequency of term to cluster out related term which is , more number of occurence of a term in same document with my query term (India) , the more likely it would be related . But the problem is that it also relates verbs , pagemarks , reference keywords etc. from the documents

My questions are :

1) How to make this technique reliable and avoid unrelated terms ?

2) What is the most easiest but reliable technique other than this one ?

Comment: I think this link will be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544266/algorithm-to-find-related-words-in-a-text. In my opinion, topic model (LDA) is a good choice